# CloudWatch alert when a new deploy is made AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

There are some issues in a company I'm working for. Basically the dev team is pushing new deploys to the API Gateway before consulting with the security guy.

This leads to the security person noticing a new endpoint on the application was released when security issues start to arise.

I was wondering if there's any simple way of creating an alert that pops up on AWS CloudWatch when a new deploy is created. If I recall corectly, these are called "alarms".

I have looked a bit into alarms but they seem to be based on metrics and I was not able to find a metric that shows a new endpoint being created on deploy.

This is certainly not the best approach to the problem, but It should work for now until the deploy process is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking you could come up with a script that runs `aws cloudformation list-stacks` and check whether the output has more number of stacks than last time. But this method will only work for new stacks, not for stack modifications.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!. A script that checks resources on a certain API and compares them to previous states could also be done I think. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: ya thats if you just want to monitor a single api